# Batch: Checking if any variables are equal

Tags: batch-file

Thanks to Aacini, I now have a way to sort variables from greatest to least.

Link:
[Comparing and ordering multiple numbers in batch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32442863/comparing-and-ordering-multiple-numbers-in-batch)

However, if 2 or more of my variables are the same value, they won't be sorted. I'm trying test to see if two variables in the set are equal. I tried using if statements against each variable in any combination I could think of, but that isn't very efficient and is hard to change.

Is there a way I can achieve this?

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set speed1=190
set speed2=78
set speed3=78
set speed4=23

rem Get the descending order of previous elements via "order" array
for /L %%i in (1,1,4) do (
   set /A num=1000-speed%%i
    set order!num!=%%i
 )

rem Show the elements of "speed" array in descending order
for /F "tokens=2 delims==" %%i in ('set order') do (
   echo speed%%i = !speed%%i!
)
```

Output will only display:

```
speed1 = 190
speed3 = 78
speed4 = 23
```

Comment: What do you mean with "if any of them are equal to another"? If two variables in the set are equal? or, If any variable in the set is equal to an external one?

Comment: If two variables in the set are equal. Sorry for the terrible explanation, I'll try to edit my post to fix that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Excuse me. I don't know if you are really interested to know if two elements have the same value, or just to fix the bug of my previous solution (that don't include the elements with the same value), so I opted for solve previous bug:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set speed1=190
set speed2=78
set speed3=78
set speed4=23

rem Get the descending order of previous elements via "order" array
REM Insert a second index to differentiate elements with the same value
for /L %%i in (1,1,4) do (
   set /A num=1000-speed%%i
    set order[!num!][%%i]=%%i
 )

rem Show the elements of "speed" array in descending order
for /F "tokens=2 delims==" %%i in ('set order') do (
   echo speed%%i = !speed%%i!
)
```

Comment: I was interested in finding a way of checking if two elements have the same value, so I could insert that code into your previous answer. I was not aware that your previous answer had a bug; I thought that 2 equal values could not be sorted using the order array. This solves my problem. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```dos
@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion

    set speed1=190
    set speed2=78
    set speed3=78
    set speed4=23

    for /f "usebackq tokens=1,2 delims=/" %%a in (`
        cmd /q /e /c "for /f tokens^=1^,2^ delims^=^= %%c in ('set speed') do (set /a %%d + 10000000 & echo /%%c)"
        ^| sort /r
    `) do (
        set /a "value=%%a-10000000"
        echo %%b=!value!
    )
```